# index set beyond bounds with objectsAtIndexes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I don't understand what is going on. As you can see I have an array of 107 objects. When I try to copy only 10 objects from it to another array I get this error.
(If I input numbers like 3,8 it will work fine)

```
    int count = [myJson count];
    NSLog(@"count: %d",count);
    resultsArray = [myJson objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(60, 70)]];
```

...

```
[53269:11303] count: 107
[53269:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:]: index 129 in index set beyond bounds [0 .. 106]'
```

Comment: Answer is within the question. Your array have only 106 objects, you are trying to access 129 th object. Your `NSRangeMake` causes the issue. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakeRange

Comment: -1 For misusing NSRangeMake.  The documentation clearly explains how it works.

Comment: I was sure both of the values are indexes... thanks for help and the -1. I needed that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSMakeRange(i,l). i is for index and l is for lenght. 
 NSMakeRange(60, 70) means objects from 60 index to next 70 elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you want 10 objects, then you have to set the range as

```
NSMakeRange(60, 10)
```

This will take the objects from 60 to 79.

Comment: I think it's 69 instead 79 in your example...

Answer (score 0):

`NSMakeRange` has two arguments, but they aren't 'start' and 'end', they are 'location' and 'length'...

So `NSMakeRange(60, 70)` is a range from `60` to `130`, which is out of bounds in your array of 107 elements.

To fix this, use `NSMakeRange(60, 10)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access element from index 60 to 70 more elements.So in this case you are getting this error.

```
    int count = [myJson count];
    NSLog(@"count: %d",count);
    resultsArray = [myJson objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(60, 10)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMakeRange(60, 70);
```

above statement will fetch 70 elements starting from 60th position
by that logic u should have 60+70 = 130 or more that 130 elements in your array.

so if you want elements from 60 to 70 then use following

```
resultsArray = [myJson objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(60, 10)]];
```